# Is there any alternative Scipy fsolve for python?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm sure this question has been addressed several times but unfortunately, none of the methods presented helped my situation.
I am trying to solve a complicated study using Scipy fsolve, but the solver is extremely sensitive to the initial conditions.

My question: Is there any alternative fsolve? if not is there any way to adjust the sensitivity?

Comment: To get a better answer you may need to discuss what alternatives you looked at, and why the failed.

Answer (score 0):

For fsolve, you can adjust the xtol so that it terminates if the relative error is at most xtol (i.e. convergence parameter). Meaning that xtol measures the relative error desired in the approximate solution. Toggling this will decrease the sensitivity of the solver. You can find out to change that in the scipy docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're solving an equation `f(x) = 0` with `fsolve` you can sometimes replace it with solving for minima in the function `|f(x)|²` using [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) or [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)